# What is wrong with this VBA ADO Class?

Tags: class, excel, vba

I am trying to make my first use of a class and need to access a database.
I found this free class online and want to use it.
http://www.thevbzone.com/cADO.cls

First, I added reference to  Microsoft Activex Data Objectx 2.8 for ADODB access.
I am developing on my Win 7 laptop for an XP server that will soon get a "virtual Win 7" upgrade (whatever that means.)

I created a new Class Module and named it cADO.
The top lines show in red in my editor - specifically the VERSION and ATTRIBUTE lines.

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
  Persistable = 0  'NotPersistable
  DataBindingBehavior = 0  'vbNone
  DataSourceBehavior  = 0  'vbNone
  MTSTransactionMode  = 0  'NotAnMTSObject
END
Attribute VB_Name = "cADO"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = True
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = False
Attribute VB_Exposed = False
Option Explicit
```

1) Have you used this class? Is it good or is there a better one?
2) What are the VERSION and ATTRIBUTE lines for?
3) How can I fix them so they compile?

Thank you.
Shari W.

Comment: Never used or even saw that class, but you don't import a pre-made class in this way. Right click on the project tree - Import file.

Comment: THe lines are red indicative of a syntax error. I don't think those lines are how you instantiate a class object in VBA.  I would suggest simply importing the `.cls` or otherwise copying/pasting the contents of that web page in to the class module.

Comment: The link I believe is for VB, not VBA.  It's similar, very similar in fact, but not the same.  Try using every code including & below the `Option Explicit` and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks guys. I feel like a dummy - didn't realize it was only for VB not VBA. Both suggestions helped. Now I am not sure what to use instead. Do you know of a premade VBA class or do I have to start all my ADO from scratch?

Comment: I would get ADO access to your database working in a normal module first and then look at turning that into a class instead. If you specify the type of database you're trying to connect to then it will be easier to explain the steps you need to take

Comment: If you could specify what problem you are trying to solve with a custom ADO wrapper, we may be able to provide more help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer comes from various user comments.

1. A VBA class is a little different from an Excel VBA class. Several types of modifications are necessary to get a VBA class to work in VBA Excel.
2. Importing a VBA class into VBA Excel using the import command will remove some of the incompatibilities, but there is still work to do.

Thanks to all who helped.